# Django - how to NOT receive email error reports for HTTP 503 status code?

Tags: python, django, email, http-status-code-500, http-status-code-503

I configured Error Reporting for my django app so it will send an report by email to those who i specified in `ADMINS` list in `settings.py` (see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/error-reporting/#server-errors)). it works perfectly well.

Based on **[official django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/error-reporting/#server-errors)**, it will trigger whenever a `HTTP 500 or greater` status code raised:

> When DEBUG is False, Django will email the users listed in the ADMINS
> setting whenever your code raises an unhandled exception and results
> in an internal server error (**strictly speaking, for any response with
> an HTTP status code of 500 or greater)**.

How to override this behavior?

To be specific, i want receive emails **just** when `HTTP 500` raised.

### More Details:

Sometimes i enable **maintenance mode** in my app, so each request will responded by a `HTTP 503` code, and since `503 > 500` , django sends me an email for each request! i wanna somehow override this behavior.